# Why is GLSL log returning the wrong result? (Intel Driver)

Tags: opengl, math, glsl, driver

I am doing some maths on the GPU and reading the result.

And I am getting the wrong value From log. I have verified this for values 0 - 10, 20, 30, 40.

If I hard code the value (as you can see bellow under verify) I get the right result spat out. However if I use log with the hard coded value that should return the same result, I get the wrong result spat out.

This is the kind of thing I have been doing in my function.

```
vec4 IScale(vec4 value)
{
    switch(uScaleType_i)
    {
        case Log:

            //value = log(value);

            value = vec4(1,1,1,1);
            value.r = log(5);
            //verifiy
            //value.r = 0.698970004     
        break;
        case Sqrt:
            value = sqrt(value);
        break;
        case None:
            break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

I am wondering is there any sense here. I have added the results of what I am getting back into excel and done a graph. At first Its almost like its double the correct value but its not quite that clean, it gets further and further away.

Is there any other explanation for this other than a driver issue? I cant think of anything else to check!

And if so how can i possibly work around it, other than refactoring my code to do it on the CPU? And why can't I find evidence online to back this up? I am completely utterly baffled!

I am running on a laptop with:
 (Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 with 132 ext.)

p.s. Sqrt is fine and I get the values I would expect.
p.p.s I checked, I have not accidentally created a function called "log"

[image]
[image]

Comment: I do feel silly now! hopefully this will help someone else having an off day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are tripping over the base used for the log. In Excel the base is 10 however in glsl it is e.

To get the right result you should divide the result with the log of the base you want.

```
value = log(value)/log(10);
```

Or in excel you can use `LN(RC[-1])`

Comment: you are both awesome, now everything is right in the world! cant believe i missed that!

Answer (score 3):

This is as per [the specification](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/log.xhtml). `log()` will return the natural logarithm, i.e. the logarithm to the base `e`. Not the base 10 logarithm.

Comment: you are both awesome, now everything is right in the world! cant believe i missed that!

Comment: ratchet beat you by 1 minute so I will give him the best answer score, but +1 for the specification link, I had looked at it and completely missed it!

Comment: Actually,  I beat him :p But it's not a contest and his explanation is solid. Leave it as is. Thanks for the upvote. ;)